# how can skip files when you don't have permission when you want use listfiles at java?

Tags: java, recursion

With below code I print all sub directories but if I cannot access one of the sub directory this code breaks and returns an error.

How can i fix it?

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    File[] files = new File("C:/").listFiles();
    showFiles(files);
}

public static void showFiles(File[] files) {
for (File file : files) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Directory: " + file.getName());
        showFiles(file.listFiles()); // Calls same method again.
    } else {
        System.out.println("File: " + file.getName());
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Catch the exception and `continue`?

Comment: if you cant access then `.listFiles()` will return null. just do a null check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--) for `listFiles` about what it returns:

> The array will be empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if
>   this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error
>   occurs.

In order to make your code fail-safe, do this:

```
public static void showFiles(File[] files) {
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory: " + file.getName());
            try {
                File[] dirFiles = file.listFiles();
                if (dirFiles == null) {
                    System.out.println("Not a directory, or I/O error: " + file.getName());
                }
                else if (dirFiles.length == 0) { //simple recursion would not recognize this case
                    System.out.println("Directory is empty: " + file.getName());
                }
                else {
                    showFiles(dirFiles); // Calls same method again.
                }
            }
            catch (SecurityException exc) {
                System.out.println("SecurityException with: " + file.getName());
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("File: " + file.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer you got there. And "interesting" nickname and profile information.

Comment: this is useful answer

Comment: @mohammadseyedi Good to know. you can mark the answer as useful by clicking on the upper arrow on the left.

Comment: this answer has funny problem never print "Not a directory, or I/O error: " until you delete this command System.out.println("File: " + file.getName()); after that its work correctly. i cant understand why??

Comment: @mohammadseyedi Not funny and not even a problem. Your code initially checks for `file.isDirectory()`, so `dirFiles == null` can only be true in case of an I/O Error. so you can either remove the check for directory or adjust the output message.

Comment: I am afraid of zombies tough.